# Firebase Messaging iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios14

I have had Firebase Cloud Messaging setup in my app for a while.  I recently updated one of my devices to iOS 14, and stopped receiving them on that device.  A different device with iOS 13 still receives them.  I'm sorry if this is a dumb issue haha but here is my App Delegate:

```swift
let appDelegate : AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
    
    var customerId = ""



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        // Update this to your stripe PUBLISHABLE KEY
        STPPaymentConfiguration.shared().publishableKey = "private"
        
        let apiToken = "private"
        EasyPostApi.sharedInstance.setCredentials(apiToken, baseUrl: "https://api.easypost.com/v2/")
        STPTheme.default().accentColor = .red
        
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
      Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
      print(userInfo)
    print("test")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print(userInfo)
        print("test")

      completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    
    func registerForPushNotifications() {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
          if let error = error {
            print("Error fetching remote instance ID: \(error)")
          } else if let result = result {
            print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
          }
        }
        
    }

}
```

I have tried sending messages using both the "test" button in the firebase console, and just publishing a message like normal.  It does register for notifications properly, and after checking settings, it still looks correct.

Comment: I have the same issue only on iOS 14 device as well

Comment: is your  `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)`  get called?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact issue. A fix I found for now was to disable method swizzling:

- To your iOS app Info.plist, add `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` and set it to FALSE (boolean value 0)

Looks like you already have `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` setup, so keep that as it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Disabling method swizzling did the trick. There are few other changes that have to be made, so future readers should follow https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client instructions again.

Comment: After hours of trying to debug this issue, it was disabling method swizzling that solved it for me. Thank you for the tip!