# I'm not able to get FCM token in iOS 14.1 SwiftUI, what could be the issue?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to both SwiftUI and Firebase Messaging. I am currently attempting to obtain my FCM token and this is what my AppDelegate file looks like:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseMessaging
import os
import SwiftyJSON
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.black
        
        AppManager.shared.token = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "keyAcccessToken") as? String ?? ""
        
        let a:String = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userLoginData") as? String ?? ""
        if a != "" || !a.isEmpty
        {
            let encodedData:Data = a.data(using: .utf8)!
            let final = try! JSON(data: encodedData)
            let user = User(json: final)
            //        print(user)
            AppManager.shared.user = user
        }
        
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(nil, forKey: "ProfileImageData")
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(0, forKey: "selectedToken")
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "isSelected")
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(false, forKey: "ADDBANK")
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(false, forKey: "IsEditPaymentDIalod")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        
        //==========
        //REMOTE NOTIFICATION
        
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        
        let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
        print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        os_log(.error, "\(#function) Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken as Data
    }
    
    // MARK:- Messaging Delegates
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        
        os_log(.info, "FCM token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
        let token = fcmToken ?? ""
        print("token didReceiveRegistrationToken --> \(token)")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "DeviceToken")
        
    }
    
}

extension AppDelegate  {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegister notificationSettings: UNUserNotificationCenter) {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    
    //Called to let your app know which action was selected by the user for a given notification.
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {


        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as NSDictionary
        //        self.notification_refesh_start()
        print("Notif Response --->\(userInfo)")
                
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(userInfo, forKey: "userInfo")

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "OnNotificationTap"), object: ["userInfo": "\(userInfo)"])
        }
        
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.OnReceivePushNotification,object: nil, userInfo: ["info": "Test"])

        completionHandler()
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
            print(#function)
        completionHandler([.banner, .list, .sound, .badge, .alert])
        
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo as NSDictionary
        print("Notif Response --->\(userInfo)")
        
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.OnReceivePushNotification,object: nil, userInfo: ["info": "Test"])
        
        }
  
}
```

This is my code for main app:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import os

@main
struct iunctaApp: App {

  @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor private var appDelegate: AppDelegate

  init() {
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    Messaging.messaging().isAutoInitEnabled = true

    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
      guard user.isEmailVerified else {
        try? Auth.auth().signOut()
        return
      }
    }
    
    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(named: "azure")

    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
  }

  @State var showExpose = !ProfileManager.shared.profiles.isEmpty
  @State var carouselState = CarouselStateModel()


  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      MainTabBarViewController(showExpose: $showExpose)
        .environmentObject(NotificationManager.shared)
        .environmentObject(ProfileManager.shared)
        .environmentObject(AssociatedManager.shared)
        .environmentObject(TransactionManager.shared)
        .environmentObject(CountryListManager.shared)
        .environmentObject(TokenManager.shared)
        .environmentObject(CategoryManager.shared)
        .environmentObject(ShippingAddressManager.shared)
        .environmentObject(BrandsManager.shared)
        .environmentObject(ProfileManager.shared.profiles.first ?? ProfileViewModel())
        .environmentObject(UserPaymentManager.shared)
        .environmentObject(FavoriteBrandsManager.shared)
        .environmentObject(carouselState)
        .environmentObject(ButtonSelectionManager())
        .environmentObject(AddressButtonSelectionManager())
        .preferredColorScheme(.light)
    }
  }
}
```

I have reviewed the official document at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client. Despite setting FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to FALSE in my info.plist file as per this [Firebase Messaging iOS 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62665568/firebase-messaging-ios-14), I am still receiving a nil FCM token on iOS 14.1. I have tested on a real device (iPhone 8) with no success. However, I am successfully receiving FCM tokens on iOS 16 and iOS 15. I have been searching for solutions for the past two days with no luck.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance. Thank you in advance!